# External ID missing error on all records even external id is there on some of them

Tags: trigger, dmlexception

I have a use case where i have to upsert records through trigger matching external id.
i am using below in trigger for dml

**Database.upsert(listToInsert,plan_product__c.Fields.External_Product_Key__c, true);**
Where External_Product_Key__c is the external keys defined on plan_product__c objects.

I was expecting above dml statement to keep trying upserting for all objects with matching external keys, but its throughing error even in case when external keys exist for products. All records including products where external exist are errored out. Any Suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53214/discussion-on-question-by-david-mycka-external-id-missing-error-on-all-records-e).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not understanding what the `allOrNone` flag is doing.

> allOrNone
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> The optional allOrNone parameter specifies whether the operation allows partial success. If you specify false for this parameter and a record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed. This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which records succeeded, which failed, and why.

Comment: Its working as expected, could you please guide me when we run the dataloader with 100 records for example, i would like to those records to go into error.csv file generated by dataloader stating external id is missing.

Comment: @DavidMycka - If using data loader any record(s) that fail will be output to the errors csv. Have you actually tried it?